# Simple Python job vacancies downloader

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have created a BeautifulSoup vacancies parser, which works, but I do not like how it looks. Therefore, I'd be very happy if somebody could give me any improvements.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urlopen('http://rabota.ua/zapros/python/%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
vacancies = {}

a = soup.find_all("a", class_="t")
inx = 0
for x in a:
    inx += 1
    vacancies[inx] = {'position': x.contents[0].strip(),
                      'link': 'http://rabota.ua{}'.format(x.get('href'))}

a = soup.find_all("a", class_="rua-p-c-default")[2:]
inx = 0
for x in a:
    inx += 1
    vacancies[inx].update({'company': x.get_text()})

for x in vacancies:
    print('{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(vacancies[x]['company'], vacancies[x]['position'], vacancies[x]['link']))
```

Here is the HTML code:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/31562) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Apart from what @MathiasEttinger suggested, I'd also ask for a description about what this code is trying to do.

Comment: A screenshot isn't ideal. Please [edit] your post to replace it with the actual HTML markup.

Comment: @Mat'sMug True, but in some ways a prettified view of the DOM tree is preferable to a dump of nasty-looking HTML.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Use `requests` instead of `urllib`. This is mostly a matter of preference but I think you'll find it easier to work with.

An example on how this would look is:

```
import requests

page = requests.get('http://rabota.ua/zapros/python/%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2').content
```

2. **Fix the bug**

In some cases you'll get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   http://rabota.ua/company209907/vacancy6312501
>       vacancies[x]['link'])) `UnicodeEncodeError`: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 26-33: ordinal not in range(128)

Which means you're trying to parse characters which cannot be decoded as they are. I'd recommend using the `encode` function to get rid of it:

```
for x in vacancies:
    print('{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(
        vacancies[x]['company'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
        vacancies[x]['position'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
        vacancies[x]['link'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
```

Instead of using a counter, you could use the builtin that Python already has: `enumerate()`.

This:

```
inx = 0
for x in a:
    inx += 1
    vacancies[inx].update({'company': x.get_text()})
```

Will become:

```
for counter, x in enumerate(a, 1):
    vacancies[counter].update({'company': x.get_text()})
```

So far, we have this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('http://rabota.ua/zapros/python/%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

a = soup.find_all("a", class_="t")

vacancies = {}
for counter, x in enumerate(a, 1):
    vacancies[counter] = {
        'position': x.contents[0].strip(),
        'link': 'http://rabota.ua{}'.format(x.get('href'))
    }

a = soup.find_all("a", class_="rua-p-c-default")[2:]

for counter, x in enumerate(a, 1):
    vacancies[counter].update({'company': x.get_text()})

for x in vacancies:
    print('{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(
        vacancies[x]['company'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
        vacancies[x]['position'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
        vacancies[x]['link'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
```

**Other suggestions:**

I'm not a fan of your naming conventions:

- `a` might become `href_tag`
- `x` might become `element`

More, I'd split everything into functions as this will make your code readable and easier to maintain:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'http://rabota.ua/zapros/python/%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2'


def get_html():
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, 'lxml')


def parse_html():
    content = get_html()
    href_tag = content.find_all('a', class_='t')

    vacancies = {}
    for counter, element in enumerate(href_tag, 1):
        vacancies[counter] = {
            'position': element.contents[0].strip(),
            'link': 'http://rabota.ua{}'.format(element.get('href'))
        }

    href_tag = content.find_all("a", class_="rua-p-c-default")[2:]

    for counter, element in enumerate(href_tag, 1):
        vacancies[counter].update({'company': element.get_text()})

    for element in vacancies:
        print('{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(
            vacancies[element]['company'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
            vacancies[element]['position'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
            vacancies[element]['link'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_html()
```

Yet another way of splitting the logic of your program:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'http://rabota.ua/zapros/python/%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2'


def get_html():
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, 'lxml')


def get_position_and_link(content):
    href_tag = content.find_all('a', class_='t')

    vacancies = {}
    for counter, element in enumerate(href_tag, 1):
        vacancies[counter] = {
            'position': element.contents[0].strip(),
            'link': 'http://rabota.ua{}'.format(element.get('href'))
        }

    return vacancies


def update_info(content):
    company_href_tag = content.find_all("a", class_="rua-p-c-default")[2:]
    vacancies = get_position_and_link(content)

    for counter, element in enumerate(company_href_tag, 1):
        vacancies[counter].update({'company': element.get_text()})
    return vacancies


def main():
    content = get_html()
    vacancies = update_info(content)

    for element in vacancies:
        print('{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(
            vacancies[element]['company'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
            vacancies[element]['position'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
            vacancies[element]['link'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can see that I also added `if __name__ == '__main__'`. By doing the main check, you can have that code only execute when you want to run the module as a program and not have it execute when someone just wants to import your module and call your functions themselves.

As [@Mathias](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146384/simple-python-vacancies-downloader/146389#comment275021_146389) suggested in comments, instead of using the `encode()` function, you might as well do:

```
def main():
    content = get_html()
    vacancies = update_info(content)

    for element in vacancies:
        for info in ('company', 'position', 'link'):
            print(vacancies[element][info])
        print('\n')
```

The advantage of this method might appear when you have a lot of unrecognised ascii characters which, with the first version, may lead to something like: `.,.`.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, thank you! I will study it and correct mistakes.

Comment: Why not suggest `for info in ('company', 'position', 'link'): print(vacancies[element][info])` instead of using `encode`?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I just wanted to avoid the nested `for` loop ^_^ But if I think of it, it might return better results so I'll add it just for OPs' info. Thanks for head-ups

Answer (score 6):

Building on [@Dex'ter answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/146389/84718), I think that using a dictionary to store your results call for the wrong iteration patterns. I would store them in a list and grab them directly with a `for` loop when I need them.

Building becomes something along the lines of:

```
vacancies = [{
    'position': element.contents[0].strip(),
    'link': 'http://rabota.ua{}'.format(element.get('href')),
} for element in href_tag]
```

Updating would be:

```
for vacancy, company in zip(vacancies, company_href):
    vacancy.update({'company': company.get_text()})
```

And printing can be as simple as:

```
for vacancy in vacancies:
    print(vacancy['company'], vacancy['position'], vacancy['link'], sep='\n')
```

Writting that, I think that using the whole building + updating technique is also a poor decision as you could build everything at once:

```
href_tag = content.find_all('a', class_='t')
company_href_tag = content.find_all("a", class_="rua-p-c-default")[2:]

vacancies = [{
    'position': element.contents[0].strip(),
    'link': 'http://rabota.ua{}'.format(element.get('href')),
    'company': company.get_text(),
} for element, company in zip(href_tag, company_href_tag)]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I was just thinking how to get rid of the double cycle. I also thought how to do only one find_all instead of two, for example content.find_all("a", class_="rua-p-c-default t") is this real?

Comment: @Vadim Reading [the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list), I think `content.find_all('a', class_=['t', 'rua-p-c-default'])` should work. But you will get a single list as output containing both classes (and probably interleaved too).